# C program to find a prime number

Tags: c, function, for-loop, primes

I wrote a C program which tells whether a given number is prime or not. But it has a problem in it. It is working fine for numbers other than multiples of 5. But it is showing the multiples of 5 as prime like 15, 25, 35, 45... . I am not able to find the error. I've tried comparing it with other programs on the internet but I am not able to find the error.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int primeornot(int a) {
    int i;

    for (i = 2; i <= a / 2; i++) {
        if (a % i == 0) {
            return 0;
            break;
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
    }
}

main() {
    int number_given_by_user;

    printf("Enter a positive integer to find whether it is prime or not : ");
    scanf("%d", &number_given_by_user);

    if (primeornot(number_given_by_user)) {
        printf("The given number is a prime number");
    } else {
        printf("The given number is not a prime number");
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `primeornot` has a pretty big issue, you should check all modulus then return 1 for prime number. try with 9, 39 etc

Comment: Yeah, I implemented it.

Comment: You will also want to look at [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) if you are concerned about an efficient approach to finding all primes.

Comment: There are lots of questions about finding prime numbers; some of them even feature most of the mistakes you've made.  Note that `i < a/2` is expensive; you can limit it to `i <= sqrt(a)`.  Indeed, if you test for divisible by 2 first, you can then test only odd numbers (`i += 2`), which also speeds things up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not only multiples of 5 (for example, 9 is also considered prime by your code)

Your code is flawed. You are using a loop but only checking the first iteration, since you have a `return` inside each branch of the condition inside your loop:

```
for(i=2;i<=a/2;i++)
{
    if(a % i == 0)
    {  
        return 0;    // <------- (this one is fine, since finding a divisor means outright that this number isn't a prime)
        break;       //  also, a break after a return is redundant
    }
    else
    {
        return 1;    // <------- (however, this one is flawed)
    }
}
```

In this form, your code only does `return !(input % 2)` which is not a very good prime finding algorithm :-)

What you need to do is check all the iteration, and only if all of them go to the `else` branch, the number is prime.

So, change to:

```
int primeornot(int a)
{
int i;

for(i=2;i<=a/2;i++)
{
    if(a % i == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        continue;
    }
}
return 1; // loop has ended with no divisors --> prime!!
}
```

Or, better yet:

```
int primeornot(int a)
{
int i;

for(i=2;i<=a/2;i++)
{
    if(a % i == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
return 1; // loop has ended with no divisors --> prime!!
}
```

Comment: `return 0` and `break` seems redundant together.

Comment: Indeed. has no effect on the code, but right nevertheless, thanks

Comment: "else continue" is also redundant ;)

Comment: yes, but it makes for a clearer flow for a beginner coder, doesn't it?

Comment: I think the "proof is in the pudding" there, and another prime example of why *"readable code"* is always better than *"clever, shorter code"*.

Answer (score 1):

Function `primeornot` returns immediately after the first test. You do not test every divisor up to `a / 2` as you intend.

Note also that testing every number up to `a / 2` is wasteful, you can stop when `i * i > a`.

Here is a corrected version:

```
int primeornot(int a) {
    int i;

    for (i = 2; i * i <= a; i++) {
        if (a % i == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

You can further improve the function by testing 2 once and only odd numbers thereafter:

```
int primeornot(int a) {
    int i;

    if (a != 2 && a % 2 == 0)
        return 0;

    for (i = 3; i * i <= a; i += 2) {
        if (a % i == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Finally, the prototype for `main` without arguments is `int main(void)` and your should output a newline after the messages and return `0`:

```
int main(void) {
    int number_given_by_user;

    printf("Enter a positive integer to find whether it is prime or not: ");
    scanf("%d", &number_given_by_user);

    if (primeornot(number_given_by_user)) {
        printf("The given number is a prime number\n");
    } else {
        printf("The given number is not a prime number\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are returning if it is not divisible so the iteration will happen only once in for loop ! Because you are returning any way ! The below code will work for you !

```
#include<stdio.h>

int primeornot(int a)
{
    int i;
    for(i=2;i<=a/2;i++)
    {
        if(a % i == 0)
        {
            return 0;
            break;
        }

    }
    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    int number_given_by_user;

    printf("Enter a positive integer to find whether it is prime or not : ");
    scanf("%d",&number_given_by_user);

    if(primeornot(number_given_by_user))
    {
        printf("The given number is a prime number");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("The given number is not a prime number");
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#include<stdio.h>

int primeornot(int a)
{
    int i, number_to_increment=0;

    for(i=1;i<=a;i++)
    {
        if(a % i == 0)
        {
            number_to_increment+=1;
        }
        else
        {
            number_to_increment+=0;
        }
    }
    if(number_to_increment==2)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

main()
{
    int number_given_by_user;

    printf("Enter a positive integer to find whether it is prime or not : ");
    scanf("%d",&number_given_by_user);

    if(primeornot(number_given_by_user))
    {
        printf("The given number is a prime number");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("The given number is not a prime number");
    }
}
```

Comment: Your suggested loop, while not incorrect, is very inefficient. You're essentially using modulus to check if `a % a == 0`, which is sort of a given, really. Suppose `a` is 100, you're checking the remainder of a division by 51 all the way through 99. That's pretty much wasted time. Dividing `a` by two is the right thing to do here

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation to your solution.

Comment: Yeah it's right that the loop will take longer to execute but remember modulus and division return differently.